# Add a CSS class for page level using Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa

How can I add a CSS class for

[image]

page-level using `Sitecore SXA`.

Comment: by looking at your image, I think you want classes on each containers? right?

Comment: not like that , i have to give class for page level

Comment: Then what @alan proposed is the right solution to your problem. (y)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add classes where you want to via **Creative Exchange**, because the positions you marked are grid specific.

You can add classes via **Creative Exchange** only where you see `class` tag with `add-your-css-classes-here` token inside

You will find more about it here: [Change a site design using Creative Exchange](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/change-a-site-design-using-creative-exchange.html)

Those that you highlighted are defined here: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Bootstrap/Grid Definition` in `Placeholders Styles` section. Technically you can change them, but it is not recommended 
(SXA installation will overwrite it anyway during upgrade). They are applied to every site using this grid.

### *"How can I add a css class for page level using sitecore sxa"*

How about adding them into `body` section if you want it to be page specific?

[image]

They will be stored in `Body Css Class` field for every page

[image]

That should let you achieve your goal.